# Hbase Shell ValueFilter error - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect filter string ValueFilter(=, '723270266')"

Tags: hbase

I am trying to scan a hbase table and filter rows by a column value.

The shell command I am using:

```
scan 'audit', {COLUMNS => 'cf1:n_id', LIMIT => 1, FILTER => "ValueFilter(=, '723270266')"}
```

But, getting following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect comparator
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ParseFilter.parseComparator(ParseFilter.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ParseFilter.createComparator(ParseFilter.java:789)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter.extractArguments(CompareFilter.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ValueFilter.createFilterFromArguments(ValueFilter.java:68)
... 212 more

ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect filter string ValueFilter(=, '723270266')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the query you apply for scanning.

```
{ FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('f1', 'col_a', >, 'binary:1')" }
```

is an example for working filters in shell. The type prefix is needed for types other than string data. The family and qualifier need to be specified.

If you just need to see data, applying some filters you can use this simple tool i built  [Hbase Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hbasemanagergui/files/latest/download). You can use this tool for 0.90.4 and 0.92 versions of Hbase.

Comment: Thanks for providing an example of using SingleColumnValueFilter in the shell!